# How to find non-matching nth child rows by name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am trying to write a query to find the nth child records only where the nth child records do not match in name.

Simplified Data Structure:

> - Root (PK: id)
>
>   - Job (PK: id, FK: idRoot -> Root.id)
>
>     - Task (PK: id, FK: idParent -> Job.id, FK: idRoot -> Root.id)
>
> All ID fields are strings (I'm at the mercy of the current design, it's not ours to change)

The idea is that a sub-query will get only one match per root, and those will be evaluated against the other single match from the other roots.  Unless all of the results from the subquery match (on a specified row), they all fail.  Basically I need all nth tasks to have the same name across all of the selected roots, otherwise they all fail.

I have a query that gives me each nth child record per root (where Task is the child table).  However I can't figure out how to check for equality. Additionally this is required to work for both SQL Compact and SQL Server, which limits some functions.

This is for n = 1 (first task)

```
SELECT COUNT(r.id) as RowIndex, t.id, t.idRoot, t.Name
FROM Task t
  INNER JOIN Job j ON j.id = t.idParent
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.id, b.idParent, b.idRoot, b.StartDate
    FROM Task b
      INNER JOIN Job c ON b.idParent = c.idRec
  ) r ON t.StartDate >= r.StartDate
      AND r.idParent = j.id 
      AND t.idRoot = r.idRoot
WHERE t.idRoot IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')
  AND j.Type LIKE '%Example%'
GROUP BY t.idRoot, t.id, t.Name
HAVING COUNT(r.id) = 1
```

That gives me back something like:

```
╔══════════╦════╦════════╦════════════╗
║ RowIndex ║ ID ║ IDRoot ║    Name    ║
╠══════════╬════╬════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║  4 ║      2 ║ 1st Task   ║
║        1 ║  7 ║      3 ║ 1st Task   ║
║        1 ║ 11 ║      4 ║ First Task ║
╚══════════╩════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

So in the above results I'm correctly getting back the first task from 'Example' job types.  I can't figure out how to get results only when the Names didn't all match.  If each of the names was '1st Task', the query should return back nothing.

**UPDATE:**

[Here's a link](https://pastebin.com/LSRX85sg) to pastebin that can create the tables and load sample data.

*Query A* returns the first task for job type A, and the results show the task names don't match.  Therefore I'd want both of these task IDs to be returned.

*Query B* returns the first tasks for job type B, and the results show all task names match.  Therefore I'd want none of these task IDs returned.

Comment: What is the difference between `Job.idParent` and `Job.idRoot`?

Comment: So there's an accompanying API with the database.  In the API, you can have an idRoot and an idParent be the exact same thing.  However I verified in the database that Job only has the idRoot foreign key.  I'll update the structure to match this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following query:

```
SELECT 
r.ID 
, j.TYPE 
, t.Name 
, t.StartDate 
INTO #CoreData 
FROM root r 
INNER JOIN job j 
ON j.idRoot = r.id 
INNER JOIN task t 
ON t.idParent = j.id 
AND t.idRoot = r.id 

SELECT 
c.ID 
, c.Name 
, c.StartDate 
, c.TYPE 
, x.RowID 
INTO #CoreDataWithRowID 
FROM #CoreData c 
CROSS APPLY ( 
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS RowID 
FROM #CoreData cd 
WHERE cd.TYPE = c.TYPE 
AND cd.ID = c.ID 
AND cd.StartDate <= c.StartDate 
) x 


SELECT 
oa.* 
FROM #CoreDataWithRowID oa 
INNER JOIN #CoreDataWithRowID ob 
ON oa.TYPE = ob.TYPE 
AND oa.RowID = ob.RowID 
AND oa.ID <= ob.ID 
WHERE oa.Name != ob.Name 
UNION 
SELECT 
oa.* 
FROM #CoreDataWithRowID oa 
INNER JOIN #CoreDataWithRowID ob 
ON oa.TYPE = ob.TYPE 
AND oa.RowID = ob.RowID 
AND oa.ID >= ob.ID 
WHERE oa.Name != ob.Name
```

This will hopefully work around some of the limitations caused by SQL Server Compact Edition.

Comment: So is the `HAVING` clause here comparing all the tasks on the same Job?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working.  When I modify the database to either match or not match, the results appear to be the same regardless.  I'm testing with three tasks per job, and the idea is to only match the first task across all roots.

Comment: Just to check I understand... ```root``` to ```job``` is a one to many relationship, and ```job``` to ```task``` is a one to many relationship? And for each `root.id`, we want to make sure all the associated `task.name` are the same?

Comment: Yes on the relationship question from a database standpoint.  However we only ever are interested in a single task per root (we filter down to a single specific job type, and only want the first task from that job).  Once we have our task for that root, we compare against the single task of other roots to make sure the names are the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a bit of trouble visualizing this. If you don't mind, could you include a sample input for all three tables, and the desired output?

Comment: Sure no problem.  The desired output is exactly the same as the output I posted in the question, however I need it to not return results when Name is the same for all rows.

Comment: Ok awesome, just @ me when you've got the sample inputs available and I'll take another look :)

Comment: I just added an update to the question with a link to create the tables and load sample data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192674/discussion-between-cowthulhu-and-parrish-husband).